# No C compiler on matlab using mex, any simple compilers/solutions?

Tags: matlab, compiler-construction, remote-desktop, mex

I've been crazy on these things all day...

I installed the Matlab2010a on remote desktop (64bits windows server 2008)
then I need to use the "mex" command to recompile the code (which is already compiled at my laptop(64-bits), but it doesn't work when I copy the .mexw64 to the remote one)

But on the remote desktop, there is no Visual Studio/VC6.0. And you know it's tooooo hard and not workable to install something like that on the remote desktop...

So, are there any other solutions for me to compile the .cpp on matlab?

Thank you so much, because I've been drived crazy...Jesus...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to see what compiler is available

```
mex

Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012a\sys\lcc 
[2] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
```

The output shows that my MATLAB may use one of these two compilers to create mex files.

If I want to set up my another compiler, I have to use the following command

```
mex -setup
```

Comment: 1. the 64-bits windows don't have a LCC-win32 compiler

Comment: 2. I have not installed any version of Visual Studio, because on the remote desktop it is too much trouble. Actually I only need the C compiler to run my matlab codes, I am looking for any easier solutions.

Comment: There is no simpler solution than installing a compiler in order to compile mex files. Try to use [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279)